# Jquery validation if checkbox checked text box gets class="form-input validate required"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I use Jquery Validation to validate my form.

I have following HTML-form:

```
<form id="caller">
    <label>Phone:</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phonen" class="form-input" value="" />

    <div class="option-group check">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1"  value="1"  />
<label for="check1"><p>Need a call</p></label>          
</div></form>
```

Javascript-Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('#caller').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){}
    });
    });
 </script>
```

If the checkbox is checked, text should get class="form-input validate required".

How can I do this?

Comment: Try first reading the docs before asking: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the depends

```
$('#caller').validate({
    rules:{
        phone:{
            required: {
                depends: function(){
                    return $('#check1').is(':checked')
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5Bt5H/)

Comment: It has to be the other way right round. If you check the checkbox, then the input field hast to be required

Answer (score 0):

Add **"required"** keyword to your element:

```
<input type="text" name="validate-me" required />
```

Comment: I have to do it with the class="form-input validate required", because its a own style. And the textfield should only get this class when the checkbox is checked...